# SSRS conditional date selection expression

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, expression, iif

I have a sql ssrs report which takes data based on selected date range.

There's 2 date parameters:
date from
date till

I need the date from and date till to fill in automatically based on which date of the week it is when the report is run.

1. If it's monday, then the date from should be the monday of previous week and date till should be the sunday of previous week.
2. If it's tuesday, then the date from should be current week Monday and date till should be Tuesday and so on - Wednesday (Monday to Wednesday), Thursday (Monday to Thursday)...

Or perhaps for point 2 it would make sense to just have an expression that if it's tuesday, then select the whole current week monday to sunday as future dates simply won't return any data anyway and SSRS allows to select future dates?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use Parameter default value expression, and use   `TODAY` to have execution date, you have also date function like `DateAdd` + `IIF` for condition

Comment: Hi, a possible solution for both points:

date from 
=IIF(WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Today))="Monday",DateAdd("d", -7, Today),DATEADD("d", 1 - DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today(),FirstDayOfWeek.Monday), Today())) 

--checks if today is Monday, and if true, then takes -7 days (previous monday), if false, takes the first day of the current week.

date to 
=IIF(WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Today))="Monday",DateAdd("d", -1, Today),Today())

--checks if today is monday, and if true, then takes -1 day (sunday of previous week), if false, takes the current day.

Comment: yes this is a possbile solution, i suggest you used `Datepart` without `WeekdayName` since it changes based on server language.

Comment: Hi, @Dordi, thanks, could you plase expand, on how it should look like? My solution is based on checking if it's Monday, and your comment regarding language is true but in my case we're not planning to change the language. Perhaps your solution would be useful for others in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can these expression on the default value on your parameters:
date from:

```
=IIF(DatePart("w", Today) = 2,DateAdd("d", -7, Today), DATEADD("d", 1 - DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today,FirstDayOfWeek.Monday), Today))
```

date till:

```
=IIF(DatePart("w", Today) = 2, DATEADD("d", 1 - DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today,FirstDayOfWeek.Monday), Today)),Today)
```

DatePart("w", Today) begins on sunday that's why monday would be 2